# JavaScript Minifier Failed, probably because of ${

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay

Getting below error :-

[com.liferay.portal.util.MinifierUtil] JavaScript Minifier failed for merlin.data['buyNow'] = merlin.data['buyNow'] || {} merlin.data['buyNow']['enhancements'] =

Corresponding source code from .jsp is ::

```
<script>
    merlin.data['buyNow'] = merlin.data['buyNow'] || {}
    merlin.data['buyNow']['${command.flavorType}'] = ${command.flavorsJSON}
</script>
```

I verified this code against online Minifier, ${command.flavorsJSON} probably has issue. Replacing this with some else like var1 works fine.

(Used : https://javascript-minifier.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right `${command.flavorsJSON}` is the problem it should be like this: `'${command.flavorsJSON}'`. This way the expression Language part  `${}` will result in a string which then you can parse into an object if you wish